# An image link won't work on codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, image

Can anybody explain to me why this won't work on CodeIgniter?

```
.linkBack{
   background-image:url('/myBlog/CodeIgniter_1.7.2/pictures/arrow.gif');
 display:block;
 height:58px;
 width:105px;
 text-indent:-999px;
}  

<div class="linkBack"><?=anchor('myBlog', 'Back to Blog');?></div>
```

while this would work perfectly:

```
#linkBack {
 background-image:url(/myBlog/CodeIgniter_1.7.2/pictures/arrow.gif);
 position:fixed;
 left:10px;
        bottom:10px;
 display:block;
 height:58px;
 text-indent:-9999px;
 width:100px;
}

<a href="/myBlog/CodeIgniter_1.7.2/index.php/myBlog"  id="linkBack">Back to Blog</a>
```

it is an image used as a link...

Comment: Could you let us know in what way it won't work?

Comment: it would just display the image...but you can't click it and it is not a link to anything

Answer (score 0):

With the `url` helper loaded either via the contoller (`$this->load->helper('url');`) or via the helper array in /system/application/config/autoload.php; try:

```
anchor('myBlog',img(array('src'=>'/myBlog/CodeIgniter_1.7.2/pictures/arrow.gif','border'=>'0','alt'=>'My Blog')));
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...I'm trying it but it doesn't present the picture anywhere on my browser and there is no link to anywhere...also there is no error

Comment: 1: are you loading the url helper either in the controller or via the helper array in autoload.php? 2: if you view the source of the page, does anything show up?

Answer (score 0):

It may be something as simple as being more specific in your CSS selector (e.g. a#linkback).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for getting `img()` to work is to make sure the HTML helper is loaded in autoload.php like this:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','html');
```